# Exception occur when attempting file upload using postman

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, postman

I am using Jersey Rest Services for file upload API,It works fine when I have attached a file in Postman, but without attaching a file if I click on SEND button of Postman client exception occur.I want to show a message stating that no file is there to upload when no file is selected.
How to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Using FormDataParam from Jeysey API Should work. Hope you have mentioned that it consumes annotation with MULTIPART_FORM_DATA as MediaType and Produces annotation with the required format like JSON or XML or HTML whichever you prefer.

Comment: Yes, it is work when i attach a file in form data, but when i am sending the request without attaching file the method url inside jersey not working HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request error is shown